# Why my data from an api is still undefined?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch some data from an api and display it in jsx.First I get the users geolocation,then I call the fetch function which uses the users geolocation data to request the data from an api , afterwards
the received data from an api is used to set the weatherData state.The final step is where conditional rendering is used to show the h1 element depending if the state is defined or not.The problem is that my weatherData is always undefined,and when I try to display it returns as undefined error.Why is my weatherData undefined?

```
  import react from "react";
import {useState} from "react";
import {useEffect} from "react";

const MainWeather=()=>{



    {/*State for storing geolocation data*/}
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
    const [weatherData,setWeatherData]=useState('');

   

    {/*Fetches the data from an api*/}
const fetchData=(link)=>{
  fetch(link)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
      (result)=>{
        {/*Sets the weather data object*/}
          setWeatherData(result);
          console.log(result);
          setStatus('data set');
      },
      (error)=>{
          console.log(error)
      }
  )

}

{/*Retrieves the location from geolocation api*/}
const getLocation = async () => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
      setStatus('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
    } else {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        {/*Calls the fetch function to get the data from an api*/}
        fetchData(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&exclude={part}&appid=0ea4f961aae42bfa56f75ca058577e1e&units=metric`);
      }, () => {
        setStatus('Unable to retrieve your location');
      });
    }
  }

 

{/*Calls getLocation function on the first render*/}
useEffect(()=>{getLocation()},[])


console.log(status);
return(
 
    

<div>


{weatherData == 'undefined' ? 
<h1>undefined</h1> : 
<h1>{weatherData.current.temp}</h1> }

</div>


)

}

export default MainWeather;
```

Comment: You have added an app id , you shouldn't expose them in public sites, please remove them

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code, what you have implemented is correct , if you are using a mac you should allow browser to fetch location , in windows a popup will come to allow it , might be browser issue check it again

still I made few changes in below the above code , just refer to it

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const MainWeather = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState("");

  const fetchData = (link) => {
    fetch(link)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setWeatherData(result);
          setStatus("data set");
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };

  const getLocation = async () => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
      setStatus("Geolocation is not supported by your browser");
    } else {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          fetchData(
            `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&exclude={part}&appid=0ea4f961aae42bfa56f75ca058577e1e&units=metric`
          );
        },
        () => {
          setStatus("Unable to retrieve your location");
        }
      );
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {!weatherData ? (
        <h1>{status}</h1>
      ) : (
        <h1>{weatherData?.current?.temp} ℃ </h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainWeather;
```

You can refer to this codesandbox

[image: Edit gifted-rgb-u5ugc]